# Overriding scrollTo method in ScrollView

Tags: android

I'm trying to override scrollTo method in ScrollView on android.

I looked up the source code for View and ScrollView and it seems like when scroll is made, it will always call this method. But when I scroll through the scrollview, my method is not called. Any idea why?

Or is there any overriding point where I can be notified when a scroll is about to happen but not happened yet so that I can discard that scroll event?

Answer (score 0):

Try to override

```
protected void onScrollChanged()
```

method instead.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like `protected boolean overScrollBy(int deltaX, int deltaY, int scrollX, int scrollY, int scrollRangeX, int scrollRangeY, int maxOverScrollX, int maxOverScrollY, boolean isTouchEvent)`
  method is not called when scrollview scroll, but overScrollBy instead.

Comment: overScrollBy is not called but overScrollBy is called? It makes no sense